# loading css for iPad useragent in PHP

Tags: php, iphone, css, ipad, user-agent

I know it is possible to use media queries and JavaScript to load CSS classes if you want to target iPad's and iPhone's but is it possible to use PHP and if the user agent is iPad load "iPad.css" or iPhone load "iPhone.css" and remove the default "style.css"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this in php:

```
<?php
$isiPad = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad');

if ($isiPad == true) { 
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ipad.css">
<?php
} else {
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nonipad.css">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: how would i remove the current css file?

Comment: you can put nonipad css in the else, so you dont load both

Answer (score 1):

May be you should check client browser with

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```